# Reusable UI code in VB.NET Windows Form Application

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a Windows Form Application in VB.NET framework 4.5.
There are many forms with a text box where the user can drop an item from a treeview.
The SAME code is duplicated in every DragDrop and DragEnter event in each form.
There is a clean way to avoid code duplication?

I'm thinking about shared methods in a global class passing the textbox to handle, but I think it is not a great idea.
Can help with a good way?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just design the form once and put all the relevant code in it, then inherit that class in other forms instead of the standard `Form` class. VS even has an item template for an *Inherited Form*.